# Error in reading the 2nd,3rd,etc lines of my Java Server from Android Client

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

My Java Server only Recognizes the first line of my input. I dont know why. I have an input of multi-lined texts like

```
Kerv
Yeah
Only
```

But my Java Server only prints "Kerv", Yeah and Only are gone.
Is there something wrong in my code here?

Server Side Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TestTCP
{
    private static final int PORT = 1234;

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT, 0, InetAddress.getLocalHost());

            System.out.println("IP:  " + serverSocket.getInetAddress() + "  Port:  " +  serverSocket.getLocalPort());

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
        }

        System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4444");

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client connection
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();

                while (message != null) {
                System.out.println(message);
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();
                                        }

                System.out.println(message);
                inputStreamReader.close();
                clientSocket.close();

            } catch (IOException ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `message = bufferedReader.readLine();` Why do you expect this to read more than the first line?

Comment: Oh crap! I see. Hahaha! Thanks man! What code should i include in my "while"?

Comment: `while (message != null) {System.out.println(message);message = bufferedReader.readLine();}` add this after your `readLine` statement to read multiple statements.

Comment: I see that you ignored the advice given the last time you asked this question.  Learn about try-catch-finally and do not ignore exceptions when you are doing network stuff.

Comment: Yes! I have finally do it. Thanks to you man!